# Access camera via IP6 router on rpi3

Tags: raspbian-jessie, ipv6

I have set up a motion camera in rpi3 running jessie.
When I tried to access it from local network it works fine i.e.

http://localIP:8081

The issue now is that I'm trying to access it from outside. 
My router doesn't have port forwarding options (unitymedia). The WAN settings only show IPv6 config, so I cannot use IPv4 port forwarding. 
My rpi3 WLAN interface is configured with IPv6 and IPv4 as well.

I have tried services like noip.com, but only uses IPv4.

My question is, can I set up something that allows me to access the rpi3 connected camera from internet in a secured manner?

Thanks for your support

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

There are a (3) parts to this question:

- 1) IPv6 Connectivity
- 2) Camera Application Support
- 3) Accessing Camera via IPv6

I'll address them in turn:

1) **IPv6 Connectivity**: You need a IPv6 ***Global Unicast Address*** to achieve your goal of accessing the camera directly without a NAT.  If your ISP doesn't offer IPv6- like most ISP's in the UK- Hurricane Electric will give you a 4-to-6 tunnel with a routed /64 IPv6 Prefix for FREE (https://www.tunnelbroker.net/)   In the "Example Configurations" tab just choose your router manufacturer and they'll plug your new tunnel details into a script to talk to their side of the tunnel:

[image: Hurricane Electric Interface]

I use a MikroTik router and my Neighbour Discovery ("ND") to distribute the Hurricane Electric Ipv6 prefixes they assigned me looks like the following:

[image: Interfaces Tab of ND]

[image: Prefixes Tab of ND]

If everything is setup right you'll see your Hurricane Electric IPv6 Global Unicast Address inside the Pi:

[image: ip addr list output]

**2) Camera Application Support**: The motion detection application you're using will of course itself have to support IPv6 and you'd need to toggle it on in the appliocation's configuration.  In the example below, I use the application "motion" for my detection in my Pi-Cams: /etc/motion/motion.conf

[image: /etc/motion/motion.conf]

**3) Accessing Camera via IPv6**: Finally, you'll need to tweak the IPv6 Firewall to allow the connectivity.  The ***Destination Addresses*** and ***Destination Ports*** in my MikroTik's IPv6 FW look as follows for the application "motion" which uses Ports 8080 and 8081:

[image: Ipv6 FW config]

If your Hurricane Electric Tunnel is setup and your firewall rules are happy, you can now access the camera on an IPv6 Global Unicast Address:

[image: Browser view of IPv6 Connectivity]

And **FINALLY**: Remember that the device you are using to connect to your camera on must ALSO have IPv6 connectivity or you still will not be able to connect to your camera on its' Global Unicast Address ;-).

Hope this helps-  Terrence

Comment: If he's already got IPv6, why would he need a tunnel?

Comment: He says he's accessing the camera on a local IP and cannot DNAT IPv4 addresses.  So he'd need an IPv6 Global Unicast Address if he wants to access that Pi from outside his LAN.  But yes, if he already has a Global Unicast Address, he wouldn't need a tunnel.  I live in the UK and no ISPs seem even slightly interested in IPv6, so a Tunnel is the workaround for me.  Apologies if there was any ambiguities in my response-  T

Comment: AA has offered IPv6 for a decade now, but they're quite expensive. Other than that, yes, the UK is far behind much of the rest of the world.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but I hope it helps somebody with the same issue.

I also have a similar setup and solved the problem like this:

1. I got a universal portmapper from IPv4 to IPv6 by a internet service. Look for DSLite Portmapper with your preferred search engine.
2. Find out your public IPv6. Easy, check your modem or several internet services. Your IPv6 is usually static, if not you will need to use a DDNS in-between.  Enter this IP as portmapper destination and use some IPv4 port. Like 80 for example. The portmapper will give you a link with an IP and port like http://someProvider.com:12345.
3. Configure your modem to route all packets arriving for port 80 (destination) to your targetip. Make sure your target device has a static IP therefore.

Voila - all set up.